# Нужно ли взять в кавычки вопросы?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

*"Зачем нужна еще одна проверка? Для чего тратить лишние средства? Кому все это надо?" — задастся логичными вопросами внимательный читатель.*

Answer (score 2):

*Зачем нужна еще одна проверка? для чего тратить лишние средства? кому все это надо? —  задастся логичными вопросами внимательный читатель.*

Прописные внутри предложения можно убрать: это не правило, но тенденция. Кроме того, они, дробя фразу, отрывают последний вопрос, делая его единственным «логичным».

Кавычки не нужны также: тема вопросов умозрительная, вопросы не оглашённые, риторические и пр.